# robot_localization IMU and visual odometry from rtabmap

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-odometry, robot-localization, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realize this topic has come up a lot, but I've read every related question on here and nothing is quite working yet.

I have a depth camera and an IMU. The IMU is rigidly attached to the camera. I'm using rtabmap to produce visual odometry and localize against a map I previously created, and I've created my own IMU node called Tacyhon for my invensense MPU 9250 board.

Here are my frames and rosgraph...

[image: r_l frames]

[image: rosgraph]

The acceleration and angular velocity seem to be working fine, however, orientation is relative to camera_link, not relative to map. Thus a 90 degree rotation results in robot_localization thinking that the IMU is facing 180 degrees from its starting location, since it is 90 degrees rotated from camera_link. How can I set my acceleration and angular velocity from the IMU topic to be relative to camera link, but my orientation data to be relative to map so that r_l can fuse the orientation from the IMU with the orientation from rtabmap?

Here is my launch file.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="sextant_tachyon_node"
        type="sextant_tachyon_node"
        name="tachyon_node" />
  <node name="tachyon_transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher"
            args="0 0 0.005 0 0 0 camera_link tachyon_node 100" />

  <node pkg="robot_localization" 
        type="ukf_localization_node" 
        name="ukf_localization"
        clear_params="true"
        output="screen">
        <param name="frequency" value="100" />
        <param name="sensor_timeout" value="10" />
        <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
        <param name="odom_frame" value="odom" />
        <param name="base_link_frame" value="camera_link" />
        <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0" />
        
        <param name="imu0" value="/tachyon_node/imu" />
        <param name="odom0" value="/rtabmap/odom" />

        <rosparam param="imu0_config">
          [false, false, false,
           true, true, true,
           false, false, false,
           true, true, true,
           true, true, true]
        </rosparam>
          
        <rosparam param="odom0_config">
         [true, true, true,
          true, true, true,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false,
          false, false, false]</rosparam>
        
        <param name="odom0_differential" value="false" />
        <param name="odom0_relative" value="false" />
        <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true" />

        <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="500" />

  </node>
  

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261724/robot_localization-imu-and-visual-odometry-from-rtabmap/) by [natejgardner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22499/natejgardner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that the [sensor_msgs/Imu](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html) message contains only a single `frame_id`, yet most of them report data in two separate frames: linear acceleration and angular velocity are in the sensor frame, yet the orientation is in a world-fixed frame. `r_l` assumes that the `frame_id` is relative to the body frame, and so if you have your IMU mounted with a 90-degree offset, it's going to apply that offset. This makes sense in general, though: if I have a robot pointing at magnetic north, and its IMU is rotated so it's off by 90 degrees, that IMU is going to read 90 degrees, even though my robot is facing 0 degrees. `r_l` will correct for that, and tell you the robot is facing 0.

In your case, you have two options:

1. Handle all the transformations of your IMU data onboard, since you wrote the driver anyway. Then you can just zero out the *camera*->*IMU* transform.
2. You should do this regardless, but note that you are fusing yaw from two different sources. The yaw from your IMU presumably comes from a magnetometer. The rtabmap yaw value will likely start at 0 when you start running and your poses will be relative to that. Those two headings are not necessarily going to agree. As stated in the wiki, if you have two sources of pose information, choose the best one, and fuse the other one either (a) as a velocity, if available, or (b) enable differential mode for it.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1